# Why is there a discrepancy between predicted and nominal voltages of alkaline batteries?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, reduction-potential

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_battery), the sum of standard reduction potentials for the half reactions for alkaline battery yield $\pu{1.43 V}:$

$$\begin{align}
\ce{Zn(s) + 2 HO–(aq) &-> ZnO(s) + H2O(l) + 2 e–} &\quad E^\circ &= \pu{+1.28 V} \\
\ce{2 MnO2(s) + H2O(l) + 2 e– &-> Mn2O3(s) + 2 HO–(aq)} &\quad E^\circ &= \pu{+0.15 V} \\
\hline
\ce{Zn(s) + 2 MnO2(s) &-> ZnO(s) + Mn2O3(s)} &\quad E^\circ &= \pu{+1.43 V}
\end{align}$$

However, the reported voltage of Duracell or other alkaline batteries is $\pu{1.5 V},$ and the actual zero-load voltage of a new alkaline battery is measured up to $\pu{1.65 V}.$ Why?

Comment: Electrodes do not have standard potentials.

Comment: The standard potential is calculated or measures at all activities equal to 1. .  The manufacturers have managed to adjust the voltage by changing the activities of some of the components. Since they are all solids it looks like it might be a difficult project, but do not forget that they have a plethora of engineers against solitary you. My guess is that the hydroxide content of the electrolyte is raised converting some of the zinc oxide to zincate ion [HZnO2-] thereby increasing the zinc potential a bit. Try calling a company up, I suggest Ultralife, and ask someone in the lab.

Comment: Electrodes do have a standard potential.

Comment: Electrode and their corresponding solution have the electrode potentials. Metal alone has no meaning.

Comment: the electrode is the substance in contact with its conjugate in aqueous solution not what is stuck in the solution.

Comment: @jimchmst It is always important in case of disagreement to verify, if all talk about the same thing. // An electrode(1) consists of an electrode(2) as a conductor and a redox system, while the electrode(2) may or may not be part of this redox system. The former case is typically a metal/metal ions system.  Platinum electrode(2) in hydrogen electrode(1) or old time chinhydron (hydrochinon + p-chinone aduct) pH electrode(1) is the latter case.

Comment: @jimchmst Correction: Electrodes(2) (in the alkaline zinc cells) do not have standard potentials of electrodes(1).

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: Standard potentials are valid for $1$ molar solutions, and only for these values. Commercial cells do not have $1$ molar solutions at their electrodes.

Comment: @Maurice Standard potentials are valid for unit activities. Activity of ions in 1 M solutions is very different from 1.  E.g. in old practical procedures is said that 2 M H2SO4 has pH very close to 0.

Comment: This bickering does not help the questioner obviously conditions are not standard. there are several approaches I suggested changing the zinc potential bit. If someone has another idea lets hear it. perhaps adding a more reactive metal to the zinc, or getting MnO2 to reduce to Mn[OH]2. I always thought there was wasted energy in Mn+3 salts.